# pyusb assertion error - no usb out endpoint?

Tags: usb, pyusb

I'm trying to program (upload new messages to) a scrolling LED badge via python on Linux instead of via the windows exe. I've got a capture of a successful upload via the windows app that I'll use as a template, but at the moment I'm having trouble writing anything at all to the device.

When I run my script, I get an assertion error, which I assume means that no OUT endpoints have been found. `lsusb` seems to corroborate this, but I could be mistaken. This is basically straight from the [pyusb tutorial](http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html) with `alternate_setting` removed from `intf` because it was causing a pipe error and is *apparently* not necessary.

```
intf = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg, bInterfaceNumber = interface_number,)

ep = usb.util.find_descriptor(
    intf,
    # match the first OUT endpoint
    custom_match = \
    lambda e: \
        usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == \
        usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT
)

assert ep is not None # < assertion error
```

In case it helps, lsusb -vv for the LED badge: http://bpaste.net/show/biixy6e38A71WlCw7euU/

Any guidance would be much appreciated - I'm entirely new to USB protocol, and not great at python either.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with a laser controller in Ubuntu.